# Transforming Lambert to WGS84 in SQL Server

Tags: coordinate-system, sql-server, lambert-conformal-conic

Need to create a SQL view of calculated Lat/Lon values from an existing SQL view of County Coords.

Loaded up SQL Server Spatial Tools and registerd CLR types. Lambert generated a resource error.

```
-- Project point and linestring using Lambert Conformal Conic projection

declare @lambert Projection

set @lambert = Projection::LambertConformalConic(0, 0, 0, 0)

select @lambert.Project('POINT (45 30)').ToString()

select @lambert.Unproject(@lambert.Project('LINESTRING (10 0, 10 10)')).ToString()

select @lambert.ToString()
```

--

XY going in=(521387.001,204215.954) Need LatLon coming out.

Do you have any ideas about how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is SQL function , depends on version of the Lambert :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LambertToGPS] (@Xlambert FLOAT , @YLambert FLOAT , @LambertVersion INT )


RETURNS 
@Coordinates TABLE 
    (
        Longitude FLOAT,
        Latitude FLOAT
    )
AS

BEGIN
/*
' |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
' | Const | 1 'Lambert I | 2 'Lambert II | 3 'Lambert III | 4 'Lambert IV | 5 'Lambert II Etendue | 6 'Lambert 93 |
' |-------|--------------|---------------|----------------|---------------|-----------------------|---------------|
' |    n  | 0.7604059656 |  0.7289686274 |   0.6959127966 | 0.6712679322  |    0.7289686274       |  0.7256077650 |
' |-------|--------------|---------------|----------------|---------------|-----------------------|---------------|
' |    c  | 11603796.98  |  11745793.39  |   11947992.52  | 12136281.99   |    11745793.39        |  11754255.426 |
' |-------|--------------|---------------|----------------|---------------|-----------------------|---------------|
' |    Xs |   600000.0   |    600000.0   |   600000.0     |      234.358  |    600000.0           |     700000.0  |
' |-------|--------------|---------------|----------------|---------------|-----------------------|---------------|
' |    Ys | 5657616.674  |  6199695.768  |   6791905.085  |  7239161.542  |    8199695.768        | 12655612.050  |
' |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
*/




DECLARE  @a FLOAT, @f FLOAT, @b FLOAT,@e FLOAT, @he FLOAT,@n FLOAT,@c FLOAT,
    @Xs FLOAT , @Ys FloAT, @LambdaC FLOAT,@Lambda FLOAT, @Gamma FLOAT ,@Phi FLOAT,@NN FLOAT, @NHeCosPhi FLOAT,@X FLOAT, 
    @Y FLOAT, @Z FLOAT,@FX FLOAT, @FY FLOAT ,@FZ FLOAT,@D FLOAT,@Rx FLOAT, @Ry FLOAT , @Rz FLOAT, @Tx FLOAT, @Ty FLOAT,
    @Tz FLOAT,@Dp1 FLOAT,@R2 FLOAT, @R3 FLOAT , @ae2 FLOAT ,@Phi0 FLOAT, @Phi1 FLOAT, @R FLOAT,@L FLOAT,
    @ExpLi FLOAT,@Phiim1 FLOAT,@ESinP FLOAT,@Miaou FLOAT,@Phiip1 FLOAT


SET @a = 6378249.2     
SET @f = 1/293.466021
SET @b = @a*(1-@f)
SET @e = SQRT((@a*@a - @b*@b)/(@a*@a))

SET @he = 0.0

SET @n= CASE 
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 1 THEN 0.7604059656
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 2 THEN 0.7289686274
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 3 THEN 0.6959127966
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 4 THEN 0.6712679322
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 5 THEN 0.7289686274   
            ELSE 0.7256077650
        END

SET @c  = CASE 
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 1 THEN 11603796.98
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 2 THEN 11745793.39
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 3 THEN 11947992.52 
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 4 THEN 12136281.99
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 5 THEN 11745793.39    
            ELSE 11754255.426
        END

SET @Xs = CASE 
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 1 THEN 600000.0
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 2 THEN 600000.0
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 3 THEN 600000.0
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 4 THEN 234.358
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 5 THEN 600000.0   
            ELSE 700000.0
        END

SET @Ys = CASE 
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 1 THEN 5657616.674
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 2 THEN 6199695.768
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 3 THEN 6791905.085
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 4 THEN 7239161.542
            WHEN @LambertVersion = 5 THEN 8199695.768
            ELSE 12655612.050
        END

SET @LambdaC = 2.337229167 * PI()/180.00
SET @Gamma = ATAN ((@XLambert-@Xs)/(@Ys-@YLambert))
SET @Lambda = @LambdaC + @Gamma /@n

SET @R = SQRT((POWER (@XLambert-@Xs,2)  + POWER (@YLambert-@Ys,2)))
SET @L = (-1.00/@n)*LOG(ABS(@R/@c))

SET @ExpLi = EXP(@L)
SET @Phiim1 = 2.00*ATAN(@ExpLi)-PI()/2.00
SET @ESinP = @e * SIN(@Phiim1)
SET @Miaou = (1.00+@ESinP)/(1.00-@ESinP)
SET @Miaou = POWER (@Miaou, @e/2)
SET @Phi = 2.00*ATAN(@Miaou*@ExpLi)-PI()/2.00

 WHILE(ABS(@Phi-@Phiim1)>=0.00000000001)
 BEGIN
    SET @ESinP = @e * SIN(@Phi)
    SET @Miaou = (1.00+@ESinP)/(1.00-@ESinP)
    SET @Miaou = POWER(@Miaou, @e/2.00)
    SET @Phiip1 = 2.00*ATAN((@Miaou)*@ExpLi)-PI()/2.00
    SET @Phiim1 = @Phi
    SET @Phi = @Phiip1
 END


SET @NN= @a/SQRT(1.00-POWER(@e*SIN(@Phi),2.00))

SET @NHeCosPhi = (@NN+@he)*COS(@Phi)
SET @X = @NHeCosPhi*COS(@Lambda)
SET @Y = @NHeCosPhi*SIN(@Lambda)
SET @Z = (@NN*(1.00-@e*@e)+@he)*SIN(@Phi)


SET @D = 0.00
SET @Rx = 0.00
SET @Ry= 0.00
SET @Rz = 0.00
SET @Tx = -168.00
SET @Ty = -060.00
SET @Tz =  320.00


SET @Dp1 = 1.00 + @D
SET @FX = @Tx+@X*@Dp1+@Z*@Ry-@Y*@Rz
SET @FY =@Ty+@Y*@Dp1+@X*@Rz-@Z*@Rx
SET @FZ =@Tz+@Z*@Dp1+@Y*@Rx-@X*@Ry

SET @a = 6378137.0     
SET @f = 1.00/298.257223563
SET @b = @a*(1.00-@f)
SET @e = SQRT((@a*@a - @b*@b)/(@a*@a))


SET @Lambda = ATAN(@FY/@FX)
SET @R2 = SQRT((@FX*@FX)+(@FY*@FY))
SET @R3 = SQRT((@R2*@R2)+(@FZ*@FZ))
SET @ae2 = @a*@e*@e

SET @Phi0 = ATAN(@FZ/(@R2*(1.00-@ae2/@R3)))
SET @Phi1 = ATAN((@FZ/@R2)*1.00/(1.00-@ae2*COS(@Phi0)/(@R2*SQRT(1.00-(@e*SIN(@Phi0))*(@e*SIN(@Phi0))))))


WHILE(ABS(@Phi1-@Phi0)>0.00000000001)
    BEGIN
         SET @Phi1 = ATAN((@FZ/@R2)*1/(1-@ae2*COS(@Phi0)/(@R2*SQRT(1-(@e*SIN(@Phi0))*(@e*SIN(@Phi0))))))
         SET @Phi0 = @Phi1
    END
SET @Phi = @Phi1

INSERT INTO @Coordinates (Longitude,Latitude)
SELECT @Lambda * 180.00 / PI()  AS Longitude , @Phi * 180.00 / PI() AS Latitude


RETURN

END
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please remember, that good code (and good answers) always contain some comments in order to help other users - and yourself 3 months from now - understand it easier.